# Is "as well" used correctly in the following sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-request

> Since contemplating suicide, Maria couldn't hold normal conversations
>   anymore. They reminded her of everything she was about to lose but
>   that couldn’t **as well** keep.

The **as well** serves as emphasis. Maria could chose not to die but she has no choice, she *has* to do it.

If **as well** isn't the right phrase, then what's  a better alternative?

Comment: Strange sentence.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct way to use the verb [keep](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keep)

Comment: Can you confirm whether you are asking if you can write a sentence like this or if you are saying you have read this sentence in an English book and you are asking its meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the sentence make sense, you would need to change it a bit:

> ... **she** couldn't keep **as well**.

"That couldn't keep" would mean that the things were going to expire, like old apples.

*As well* can't go between the auxiliary and the infinitive. It works the same as *too* in that regard. If you wanted to put emphasis between *couldn't* and *keep* then you could say:

> ... she couldn't very well keep.